# SSRS dynamically grouping

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have a report I want to add dynamic group to.

If the user chooses Group By: Field1 the report will Group By Field 1 and then subsequently Field2. They are two different groups in the report. But if the user chooses Group By: Field2 I need the Field 1 group to be hidden. But if I use the formula based on the parameter to say hide, nothing appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Senario 1 User Selects - Field1 | Field2**

```
Group1 Expression=Field1.Value
Group2 Expression=Field2.Value
```

**Senario 2 User Selects - Field1**

```
Group1 Expression=Field1.Value
Group2 Expression=(1=1)
```

**Senario 3 User Selects - Field2**

```
Group1 Expression=Field2.Value
Group2 Expression=(1=1)
```

**Senario 4 User Selects - {}**

```
Group1 Expression=(1=1)
Group2 Expression=(1=1)
```